# Angular route navigate

Tags: angular, routes

I have some url that is like this

**http://www.example.com/rights?activeOnly=false&party=12345**

And i have some function that is like this

```
  cancel(): void {
      this.router.navigate([], {
        queryParams: {
          activeOnly: false
        }
      });
  }
```

The problem that i have is, when i call this function, it reacts like toggle, if there is just activeOnly in url, like this

**http://www.example.com/rights?activeOnly=false**

it just remove queryParams like this

**http://www.example.com/rights**

On second call it just add query params like this

**http://www.example.com/rights?activeOnly=false**

What i need is that route will always when function cancel is called, always be

**http://www.example.com/rights?activeOnly=false**

And to toggle values

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function to like this

```
cancel(isActiveOnly?: boolean): void {
      this.router.navigate([], {
        queryParams: {
          activeOnly: isActiveOnly ? true : false
        }
      });
  }
```

Comment: Please write correct answer, condition is undefined?